# Padding not working on overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm creating a div with the image and putting overlay on the top . when you hover on image the overlay will appear but it's not taking the padding

```
  <div class="col-lg-6 text-center full-width">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p class="overlay-price-product">
          $9.00
        </p>
        <p class="color-white">
          MENS,T-SHIRT
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="#">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default-buy">
              add to cart
            </button>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <img src="img/men_shirt_1.jpg" class="spaces">
    </div>
```

My CSS

```
.full-width{
padding-right: 0px !important;
padding-left: 0px !important;
background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

now the problem is here its taking padding for the image class but its not taking overlay class padding

```
.overlay{
opacity: 0;
transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
position: absolute;
padding: 20px;
}

.spaces{
padding:20px;
}
```

i wan't my overlay to be the exact size of image any suggestions ? or any efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, background applies to the inner space, including padding.

If you don't want this, you can change with  background-clip property. In your case,

```
.overlay {
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/em73L277/2/)

Answer (score 2):

There is another way. I will show an example. Here will be the three-type zooming effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title> Powerful Zooming Effect Using jQuery  </title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $('#image1').addimagezoom({
            zoomrange: [3, 10],
            magnifiersize: [300, 300],
            magnifierpos: 'right',
            cursorshade: true,
            largeimage: 'Image/image1.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
        })

        $('#image2').addimagezoom({
            zoomrange: [5, 5],
            magnifiersize: [400, 400],
            magnifierpos: 'right',
            cursorshade: true,
            cursorshadecolor: 'pink',
            cursorshadeopacity: 0.3,
            cursorshadeborder: '1px solid red',
            largeimage: 'Image/image2.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
        })

        $('#image3').addimagezoom()

    })

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .magnifyarea
    {
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #818181;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #818181;
        -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #818181;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=#818181, offX=5, offY=5, positive=true);
        background: white;
    }
</style>



</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<p>
    <img id="image1" border="0" src="Image/image1.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 225px" /><p>
        <p>
            <img id="image2" border="0" src="Image/image2.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 225px" /><p>
                <p>
                    <img id="image3" border="0" src="Image/image3.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 225px" /><p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code below: Here is the [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/kL742896/)

```
<div class="container">
     <img src="http://hdwallpick.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/sunshine-on-green-nature.jpg" width="200"/>
     <div class="overlay">
         <p class="overlay-price-product"> $9.00 </p>
         <p class="color-white"> MENS,T-SHIRT  </p>
         <p><button type="button">add to cart</button></p>     
     </div> 
</div>


.container{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
    position:relative;
}
.container img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.overlay{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:20px;
    top:0;
    transition:all .5s;
    transform:scale(.9, .9);
}
.overlay:hover{
    opacity:1;
    transform:scale(1, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this css in overlay class

.overlay{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your code. As you can see the padding works on the overlay.

Can you check if one of the paragraph tags inside the overlay class has some padding or margin?

Other option will be that some other css code overrides the overlay container elsewhere. You should check this with a browser inspector.

```css
.container {
    background:green;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    padding: 20px;
    background:red;
}

.overlay:hover {
     opacity:.5;      
}

.spaces {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>I'm overlay</p>
        <p class="overlay-price-product">
          $9.00
        </p>
    </div>
    <img class="spaces" src="http://hdwallpick.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/sunshine-on-green-nature.jpg" />    
</div>
```

Comment: yeah but it's not taking the padding of the class overlay in your code also https://jsfiddle.net/em73L277/